# Connect MariaDB on raspberrypi from remote over same network

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I have installed mariaDb (Mysql) on my raspberry pi .I am trying to connect my db using python from another machine over the same network but I receive the below error .

```
 self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Both my machine and raspberry pi are over the same network . I can connect when I run the code on raspberry pi using localhost but running the same code on another machine gives above error .

```
import mysql.connector
if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host='192.168.0.108',user='admin123',password='abcd',database='cdr_mapping')
    print(db)
```

Is there any config for mariadb which I need to set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open the config-file of mariadb under:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf

Change the bind-address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

And restart mariadb.

On my second DB the file looks like this:

```
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
#port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

I think I used following blog to solve the issue:

https://webdock.io/en/docs/how-guides/database-guides/how-enable-remote-access-your-mariadbmysql-database

That worked for me :D